# Add Tabbar or show tabbar in viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have implemented TabBar controller in my application, in a tab i have newsletter clicking on each news letter i am redirecting them to a viewcontroller where all post's load against that newsletter.

Here is screenshot:

[image]

On clicking on button i want to return back to tabbar controller but on the same tabbar from where it redirected to single view.

Right now i am redirecting it to tabbar controller but it disappear's the tabbar at bottom.

Here is my code:

```
 -(void)tapDetected{

    NSString * identifier=@"splashmain";
    SplashViewController * obj;
    UIStoryboard *    storyboardobj=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    obj = (SplashViewController *)[storyboardobj instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];
    self.view.window.rootViewController = obj;
}
```

In New'sletter tabbar i have placed that code as well:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
      self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = NO;
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = NO;
}
```

But it still doesn't show's the tabbar on bottom, i want a solution to show Tab bar's at bottom, or in single viewcontroller tabbar controller so that user can go to any tab.

I hope you understand my question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to create a segue to the tabBar using a custom TabBarController and from the tabBar Go to the viewController

Comment: @kholl Can you please explain? Right now from Tabbar i am able to redirect to viewcontroller properly. the issue is i want to get back from viewcontroller to tabbar which also work's but it hides the tabbar icon's at bottom,

There should be two solution:

1- Add tabbar item which should be only linked to a specific tabbar controller item in viewcontroller
2- When going back from viewcontroller it should show tabbar icon's at bottom

Comment: As I said try to create an UnwindSegue to a CustomTabBarController (search unwind segue there a tons of tutorials ) then when you get back (after the segue ) you can do your change on the tabBar and trigger a segue from the customTabBar to the viewController